# Adaptive Storyboard to scale iPhone 4 inch app to support 4.7 and 5.5 inches devices

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6.1, iphone-6

I am wokring on new app and will use Xcode 6.1.1.

I know existing iPhone 5 (4 inch) app will automatically scale up opn iPhone 6 (4.7 inch) and iPhone 6 + (5.5 inch).

The app I am currently working on is not going to do any fancy layout for its view and subviews.

All I want my app to be scale up from 4 inch to 4.7 and 5.5 inch screen when showing on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 + respectively.

I followed many tutorials but it suggested to use autolayout for each items on view achieve desire result using Auto layout and size class. I am sure there should be simple option when I just want to scale up my app.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**What should be best approch to achieve scale up app for 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch devices?**

**UPDATE**

I have add following constrain on image, view and button and got new result as shown in attach image.

**IMAGEVIEW**
[image]

**VIEW**
[image]

**Button1**
[image]

**Button2**
[image]

**RESULT**
[image]

However as you can see from picture then Button 1 and Button 2 Height is **not** increased.

Also gap between all alyout is **not** increased either so that result into empty space button of the page for 4.7 and 5.5inch screen.

Comment: you mean you want to increase height and width as per device scale right? can you tell us what layout you gave to imageview and buttons?

Comment: Hello Chintan, Yes I would like to give increase height and width as per device scale. Will update quetion with imageview and buttons layout information in few minutes!

Comment: try to give aspect ratio for button. for that drag Button to button and you will see last option will be aspect ratio. try this. only give 3 constraint leading, Trailing, Aspect ratio.  can see lots of warning and errors in constraint. you should solve all this.

Comment: set the constraint to bottom of button 2

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani Thanks Aspect ratio did help to increase button(s) size However I have to keep Top Space to: View for Button (1) and Top space to Button (1) for Button 2 to preserve location on view. I am still looking for answer on how to increase gap between all subviews (image , view and buttons) based on device size currently its constant.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for your answer! Still need answer on how increase gap between subviews based on device screen size.

Comment: if you want to increase gap and fix height. then set verticle/bottom spacing to `>=`. Still can not understand how you exactly want. Please attach screenshot.

Comment: actually u placed the constraint **Top space to bottom** , change the button constraint to bottom to top

Comment: Anbu and Chintan thanks for your comments I am actullay not try to solve problme in this given exmaple. I am looking for genraic answer that is there any simple answer to scale all subview rather then going through all view and set autolayout for each items. It will take such long time to set autolayout constraint  when we have more than 20 View controllers with at least 10 subview items on each!!

Comment: I am thinking to set my app to work perfectly on iphone 4 inch screen and it will display scale up version for 4.7 and 5.5 inch screens. Like it does currently with any existing app.